# Pycharm Python console not printing the output

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a function that I call from Pycharm python console, but no output is shown.

```
In[2]: def problem1_6():
  ...:     for i in range(1, 101, 2):
  ...:         print(i, end = ' ')
  ...: 
In[3]: problem1_6()

In[4]:
```

On the other hand, like this, it prints but in the wrong order

```
In[7]: def problem1_6():
  ...:     print('hello')
  ...: 
  ...:     for i in range(1, 101, 2):
  ...:         print(i, end = ' ')
  ...: 
In[8]: problem1_6()
1 3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19 21 23 25 27 29 31 33 35 37 39 41 43 45 47 49 51 53 55 57 59 61 63 65 67 69 71 73 75 77 79 81 83 85 87 89 91 93 95 97 99 hello
```

As a third option, as a suggestion of @DavidS,

```
In[18]: import sys
   ...: 
   ...: def problem1_6():
   ...:     for i in range(1, 101, 2):
   ...:         sys.stdout.write(str(i) + ' ')
   ...: 
In[19]: problem1_6()

In[20]:
```

It still doesn't print.

Comment: I have restarted both the console and Pycharm. This is the only code I use.

Comment: I tested too for me without the `end` it show the output but with the `end = ' '` it does not

Comment: It may be because of that, Anyway, it is still weird that `hello` is printed after the range.

Comment: @SamuelNLP try using `sys.stdout.write()`

Comment: @DavidS not working.

Comment: I've started noticing the same behavior after upgrading from 2016.3 to 2017.3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will working:

```
def problem1_6():
    for i in range(1, 101, 2):
        sys.stdout.write(str(i) + ' ')
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

or:

```
def problem1_6():
    for i in range(1, 101, 2):
        print(i, end=' ', flush=True)
```

Comment: @SamuelNLP `print(i, end=' ', flush=True)` working fine for me